# Android Beginner: Ads at the Bottom of the XML

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, admob

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Beginner: Prevent admob from pushing content up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808143/android-beginner-prevent-admob-from-pushing-content-up)

I am new to android so please bear with me. I am creating an app with a series of buttons as the home page. Whenever the ad loads, it loads awkwardly right below the buttons and pushes the ads up. How can I push the adlayout down to the bottom of the screen?

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/background_hdpi" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="7.0"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">
    <Button android:textSize="16.0sp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/basics1" android:layout_width="150.0dip" android:layout_height="0.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="100.0dip" android:layout_marginBottom="2.0dip" android:text="Overview" android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
    <Button android:textSize="16.0sp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/basics2" android:layout_width="150.0dip" android:layout_height="0.0dip" android:layout_margin="2.0dip" android:text="Campaign" android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
    <Button android:textSize="16.0sp" android:textColor="#ff000000" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/basics3" android:layout_width="150.0dip" android:layout_height="0.0dip" android:layout_margin="2.0dip" android:text="Special Ops" android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
    <Button android:textSize="16.0sp" android:textColor="#ff000000" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/basics4" android:layout_width="150.0dip" android:layout_height="0.0dip" android:layout_margin="2.0dip" android:text="Zombies" android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
    <Button android:textSize="16.0sp" android:textColor="#ff000000" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/basics5" android:layout_width="150.0dip" android:layout_height="0.0dip" android:layout_margin="2.0dip" android:text="Modes" android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
    <Button android:textSize="16.0sp" android:textColor="#ff000000" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/basics6" android:layout_width="150.0dip" android:layout_height="0.0dip" android:layout_margin="2.0dip" android:text="Ranks/Unlocks" android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:gravity="bottom"
                  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="id"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
        </com.google.ads.AdView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would recommend doing a format (control+shift+f) on that XML and then updating your post. That's incredibly difficult to read as is.

Answer (score 2):

Use relative layout as the main layout. You can then position the ad relative to the bottom. Then use the linear layout above the ad.

Something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="id"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true">
    </com.google.ads.AdView>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/ad">

     PUT BUTTONS ETC HERE

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks... this works but it still pushes the buttons up... any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean the buttons appear lower until the ad shows? I have modified the above layout to fix this (added android:layout_alignParentTop="true").